How to find the roots of sin(x) using series theory
If we define $$\sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \ x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
How to find the roots of $\sin(x)$, i.e.
$$\pi =4 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$
satisfies $\sin (\pi)=0$

Actually,  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\frac\pi4$.

Sorry, I overlooked this detail. It has been corrected.

I think you have to say what your definition of $\pi$ is. [I would define $\pi$ as twice the least positive root of $\cos(x)$, from which you can deduce the series you quote quite easily. And I'd be able to show that with this definition of $\pi$ the circumference of the unit circle is $2\pi$. But it depends where you want to start.]

In my initial thought, I hoped that pi would be the smallest positive root of sin(x), and from this, derive several properties of trigonometric functions related to π.
